# How to tell if current thread is a folly::executor thread?

Tags: c++, executor, folly

I'm writing c++ code that uses folly::executor and I want to check whether the current thread is an executor thread.

For example, something like an API static folly::Executor* folly::executor::getExecutor(), which returns a nullptr if current thread is not an executor thread.